# Poisson process and continious modifications

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

How can I prove that Poisson process dont have modification with continious paths, any idead would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the PP? I do it as follows: it counts the number of jumps whose times are sums of i.i.d. exponentially distributed waiting times. Question: what are the only continuous functions with values in $\mathbb N$? What is the probability that a   path of the PP belongs to the class of those functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Poisson process has almost surely discontinuous paths. Since it is right-continuous, it is indistinguishable from any of its right-continuous modifications. Hence any modification has almost surely discontinuous paths.

Comment: I think it is true that it is indistinguishable from any other "right-continous" modification! Not from any!

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out! Fortunately this does not invalidate the conclusion.